# API для работы с Viber. Есть опыт?

Tags: viber

Есть потребность работать с Viber, а именно:

1. Проверять наличие аккаунта Viber для контакта
2. Отправлять контактам сообщения
3. Проверять статус отправленных сообщений

Открытого API нет. Открытых библиотек нет.

Быть может кто-то сталкивался по долгу службы с такой же потребностью?
Или есть понимание, что вообще с этим можно сделать? Можно ли провести reverse engeneering протокола и нарисовать либу?

Быть может кто-то какие-то все же способы работы находил?

Comment: https://twitter.com/jimezam/status/273513462674624512 Как видите API нет и не будет. А реверс инжиниринг может быть и нелегальным :)

Comment: Уже прошло почти 4 года. Что то изменилось? если да, то киньте ссылку, где копать?

Comment: Работа через бота :
1. Проверять наличие аккаунта Viber для контакта - нельзя.
2. Отправлять контактам сообщения - только подписчикам бота,
3. Проверять статус отправленных сообщений - статус есть(получен доставлен)

Comment: @Alex https://viber.github.io/docs/api/rest-bot-api/  Может тут что-то найдете полезное.